# Man in the Middle Attack for OAuth 2's Authorize endpoint

Tags: man-in-the-middle, oauth2, oidc

We all know that the /authorize endpoint is a standard endpoint of OAuth 2. Below is how it's commonly called:

```
GET /oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&response_type=code&tenantId={tenantId}&userId={user}
```

We have introduced a custom query parameter to the authorize endpoint because we are using a Custom OAuth 2 server. UserId is the added parameter here. This is the userId of whichever user is logged in the client application that uses our OAuth 2 server to access our shopping portal.

Our custom OAuth 2 server recently underwent manual penetration testing by our security team, and it was discovered that this endpoint is susceptible to MITM attacks. They did this by using Burpsuite to intercept the request and then alter the userId param to a different value.

Let's say a client application called the /authorize endpoint with the value "Johndoe" as the userId param. Naturally, what will come next is our Oauth 2 server's login page, before it is forward to our shopping portal. They intercepted the /authorize call and changed "JohnDoe" to "JaneDoe". When this happens, you can change and login as a different user, provided that you know "JaneDoe's password. The security issue here is the user session from the client application should be the same user session that will be used for the shopping portal. Yes, you can say you cannot complete the hack if you don't know Jane Doe's password but this kind of thing bypasses the rules. If JohnDoe is JaneDoe's friend, he can change the userId to Jane's to bypass the some rules that only he is allowed to do.

Any suggestions to fix it? Tried researching and found out using Auth Code with PKCE may solve it, but this is more for protection of the /token endpoint.

Comment: Is your shopping web app using the same Oauth2 provider?

Comment: Seems like you want one login here. That still wouldn't protect Jane if John knew her password.... maybe 2-factor would be needed for that? This wouldn't be a MITM attack. It might be a vulnerability if you relied on the userid to prove anything about the identity of the user.   I don't think there's anything wrong with what you are doing.  You're making them re-enter their password to be sure... in case of stolen session?

Comment: "You can login as a different user, provided that you know [her] password": Isn't that the way it's meant to be: you can log on with a password? What's the security issue with that?